# pycorenlp: "CoreNLP request timed out. Your document may be too long"

Tags: python, timeout, nlp, stanford-nlp

I'm trying to run [pycorenlp](https://github.com/smilli/py-corenlp) on a long text and get an `CoreNLP request timed out. Your document may be too long` error message. How to fix it? Is there any way to increase [Stanford CoreNLP](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/)'s timed out?

I don't want to segment the text into smaller texts.

Here is the code I use:

```
'''
From https://github.com/smilli/py-corenlp/blob/master/example.py
'''
from pycorenlp import StanfordCoreNLP
import pprint

if __name__ == '__main__':
    nlp = StanfordCoreNLP('http://localhost:9000')
    fp = open("long_text.txt")
    text = fp.read()
    output = nlp.annotate(text, properties={
        'annotators': 'tokenize,ssplit,pos,depparse,parse',
        'outputFormat': 'json'
    })
    pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
    pp.pprint(output)
```

The Stanford Core NLP Server was launched using:

```
java -mx4g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer 9000
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add `'timeout': '50000'` (unit is ms) in the `properties` dictionary:

```
output = nlp.annotate(text, properties={
    'timeout': '50000',
    'annotators': 'tokenize,ssplit,pos,depparse,parse',
    'outputFormat': 'json'
})
```

Otherwise, you can launch the Stanford Core NLP Server specifying the timeout:

```
java -mx4g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -port 9000 -timeout 50000
```

(The [documentation](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/corenlp-server.html) doesn't mention the `timeout` parameter, maybe they forgot to add it, it's at least present in [stanford-corenlp-full-2015-12-09, a.k.a. 3.6.0.](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/history.html), which is the latest public release)

Comment: Seems like they do now but it appears that there is no unlimited timeout and they also do not specify a maximum value in the docs.

Comment: @displayname One step at a time :/

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately [the problem I'm currently having](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39809061/edu-stanford-nlp-io-runtimeioexception-could-not-connect-to-server) might have something to do with a timeout issue or something like that.